# Human body detection using opencv, tensorflow and python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, tensorflow

I am working on a robotic project that involves the detection of a human body for which I am using tensor flow and predefined data sets to create a training model. As I am new to machine learning, I am unable to properly get the output from my classifier. I require only the Person detection and want to avoid the detection of balls, laptops or other objects. 
Right now my webcam detects all the objects like ball, bat, laptops, tv etc. The output I require is only persons with a score of 80% and above.

The code I used for using the created model is

```
import numpy as np
import os
import six.moves.urllib as urllib
import sys
import tarfile
import tensorflow as tf
import zipfile

from collections import defaultdict
from io import StringIO
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image


from utils import label_map_util

from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util

MODEL_NAME = 'ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_11_06_2017'
MODEL_FILE = MODEL_NAME + '.tar.gz'
DOWNLOAD_BASE = 'http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/'


PATH_TO_CKPT = MODEL_NAME + '/frozen_inference_graph.pb'
PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join('data', 'mscoco_label_map.pbtxt')

NUM_CLASSES = 90

if not os.path.exists(MODEL_NAME + '/frozen_inference_graph.pb'):
    print ('Downloading the model')
    opener = urllib.request.URLopener()
    opener.retrieve(DOWNLOAD_BASE + MODEL_FILE, MODEL_FILE)
    tar_file = tarfile.open(MODEL_FILE)
    for file in tar_file.getmembers():
      file_name = os.path.basename(file.name)
      if 'frozen_inference_graph.pb' in file_name:
        tar_file.extract(file, os.getcwd())
    print ('Download complete')
else:
    print ('Model already exists')

detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
  od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
  with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
    serialized_graph = fid.read()
    od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
    tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')

label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, use_display_name=True)
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)

import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)


with detection_graph.as_default():
  with tf.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
   ret = True
   while (ret):
      ret,image_np = cap.read()
      image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
      image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
      boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')      
      scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
      classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
      num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')

      (boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = sess.run(
          [boxes, scores, classes, num_detections],
          feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
      vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(image_np,np.squeeze(boxes),np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),np.squeeze(scores),category_index,use_normalized_coordinates=True,line_thickness=8)
      cv2.imshow('image',cv2.resize(image_np,(1280,960)))
      if cv2.waitKey(27) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
          cv2.destroyAllWindows()
          cap.release()
          break
```

Could anyone please explain how can I detect only persons with an accuracy score of greater than 80%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The identifiers can be found in the data folder, there are 90 different identifiers for this task. Create a new text file say 'new.txt' now just copy the identifiers you require to display say you require to display persons, 
copy

```
    item {
        name : "/m/01g317"
        id : 1
        display_name : "Person"
         }
```

Then in your final code change the number of classes from 90 to 1

```
NUM_CLASSES = 1
```

Answer (score 6):

As I can see from the docs [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/data/mscoco_label_map.pbtxt), you have to check only for the person class. Right now `vis_util` checks for all classes. You have to add an `if` condition for only the person class. Given below is the appropriate identifier (taken from docs).

`item {
  name: "/m/01g317"
  id: 1
  display_name: "person"
}`